# UWP MediaElement crashes randomly

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mediaelement, windows-10-iot-core

I'm using a MediaElement to stream an HTTP audio stream on my Raspberry Pi 3 using Windows 10 IOT.

It is somehow reproducible that the touch screen freezes after some time (I have not figured out when) and after approximately half an hour, the stream stops playing. I have to restart the application to get it work again.

Any ideas how to find the cause of this problem?

I've checked the memory and error logs of the Raspberry Pi without any result.
Since there is not much code, I don't know how to debug this error.

I'm using the following implementation:

XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" 
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="true"  
              Height="100"
              AutoPlay="True"
              Grid.Row="1"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" IsCompact="True" IsSeekBarVisible="False" />
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

Starting the stream and setting the source:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("http://mp3stream7.apasf.apa.at:8000/");
    myMediaElement.Play();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
When running the application from Visual Studio in debug mode I get the error message that there is no network connection available anymore, but the webinterface (port 8080) is still available.

Comment: What about setting the source to the file retrieved from the local system, like "`new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/B889.mp3");`" ? Does it works?

Comment: Yes, this works. I've played a *.mp3 file in a loop for hours.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Visual Studio Remote Debugger issue.

As @Jackie pointed out, you can try release mode and start without debugging. I tested with your audio file for 15 hours and it works.

Comment: that is strange - I've also tested a release version without debugger and I still have these problems.

Comment: I'm using WiFi. I tried cable now and it also works - seems to be the WiFi connection. But still no idea why and how to debug.